# How to initialize variable without value

Tags: java, android

I want to show value inside Textview. But problem is that its showing 0 in my Textview. It is coming from int total=0. I am doing setText but its not giving value I want.

If I remove 0 and keep int total then it's showing variable total is not initialized. If I initialize it then it shows that value in Textview.

```
public int getTotal(ArrayList<Integer> price){
    int total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<price.size();i++){
        total= total+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price.get(i)));
    }
    return total;
}

textViewamount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.amountdisplay);
textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price));
```

Comment: Instead of `total+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price.get(i)));` you can simply do `total + price.get(i)`. And if `total` remains `0`, are you sure that your list `price` actually contains items?

Comment: Well, if want to print the value only if there is at least one price, you should start by checking if there is at least one value in the list.

Comment: *"but its not giving value i want"* What value do you want? What values are in the `ArrayList`? Why convert an `Integer` to `String` and then parse it, rather than just using the `Integer`? Note that initializing `total` to `0` is correct, so you've focussed on the wrong part of the problem.

Comment: Yes values get add in list.I have checked by Toast.It displays my required value

Comment: Is there any way we can initialize total without adding =0 to it?

Comment: what is the expected value and what are you getting ?

Comment: Expected value is addition of prices which are in arraylist.It shows that value if i check it with Toast.But in Textview it displays 0 as i have initialized total=0.If i remove initialization it gives error as total is not initialized

Comment: @Ajinkya printout or debug the values of the list, see if there are items and items are not 0.

Comment: If `getTotal(price)` returns 0, then set empty text to the `TextView` instead of the number. You can't initialize a variable without initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if the size of ArrayList is 0. In that case, the loop will not execute and it will return the initial value of total if it is set before

Comment: Wat can i do to change size of arraylist.

Comment: @Ajinkya add some actual elements to the list

Comment: @Ajinkya that means you have passed the arraylist without adding any element to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to this hope this can help you..

```
int[] price = {0, 1, 1, 10, 2, 5};
TextView total;

int total1 = 0;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total1 = 0;
            getTotal();
            total.setText("" + total1);
        }
    });
}

 private void getTotal() {

    for (int i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
        total1 = total1 + price[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: So... every time someone clicked something, total should increase and never reset? If I click three times, your program will display "Total = 57". Ten times will get me a total of "190" and so on.

Comment: yes but you can set flag for this then this problem solve

Comment: set total1 = 0; before getTotal(); in onClick

Answer (score -1):

you should change your line:

```
for(int i=0;i<price.size();i++)
{
total = total+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price.get(i)));
}
to:
for(int i=0;i<price.size();i++)
{
total+= (price.get(i)).intValue());
}
```

Comment: No if i write that line it still shows 0 in textview

Comment: 0 is going from int total=0; But if i keep int total; it shows that total is not initialized.